# Git Subtree merge strategy - how does the setup itself carry over across cloning?

Tags: git, git-subtree

When someone else clones your repository that has a subtree in it created with the merge strategy, the remotes needed for updating a subtree aren't there. Which steps of the subtree setup (following https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-subtree-merge as an example) need to be done in order to get subtree updates working after a clone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the sub-tree explicitly and independently from upstream you'll need to re-add the remote as you've indicated. In the new cloned repo:

```
$ git remote add -f <subtree-repo> <subtree-repo-url>
$ git pull -s subtree <subtree-repo> <branch>
```

For the link you gave it would be along the lines of,

```
$ git clone /Users/tekkub/tmp/test my-test-clone
$ cd my-test-clone
$ git remote add -f cork git://github.com/TekNoLogic/Cork.git
$ git pull -s subtree cork master
```

You can also use `git subtree pull` supported on the very latest version on git.

---

The dependency scenario is not clear from the question, but you can also simply pull the repo you've cloned to get all the subtree updates:

```
(repo1)
(repo2 [subtree: repo1]) -- clone --> (repo3)

repo1 $ git commit ...
repo2 $ git pull -s subtree ...
repo3 $ git pull
```

So when `repo2` updates from `repo1` you can simply `git pull` in `repo3` and you'll get all its commits. And you should use the commands above the dividing line only if you intend to sever the dependency between `repo3` and `repo2`, otherwise if you'll both `pull`, `push` upstream and `pull -s subtree` it's easy to get into frequent unpleasant merges.