# Single git repository, from dual git repositories?

Tags: git, module

I have two modules that make up a single project: one module has `nanoc` in it and generates templates for another project using node.js / express.js and gruntjs as the build file.

The entire project structure looks like this at present:

```
project_root
 - nodejs
   - .git
   - Gruntfile.js
   - etc...
 - nanocproj
   - .git
   - etc...
```

Initially I was developing these projects separately, but now I would like to develop them in parallel.

Is it possible to merge these two repositories into one using git?  I would think that if I merged the two together the changes could be kept separate because each project has feature branches that have been changed and merged back into their `master` branches.

My goal is to merge them into one project / one repository without loosing the commits i.e.:

```
project_root
 - .git
 - nodejs
   - Gruntfile.js
   - etc...
 - nanocproj
   - etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to submodules, especially for repos which are tightly linked together (you cannot make modifications to one without having to modify the other) is to consider a subtree merge: see "[How do you merge two git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1425892/6309)".

That way, you only manage one repo even though you can push back to the subtree initial repos.

You might have to pay special attention to:

- merges between subtree branches: "[git: merging a subtree from one branch to another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6433394/6309)"
- cloning a merged repos: "[Git Subtree merge strategy - how does the setup itself carry over across cloning?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20777147/6309)"

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to add the repositories as [submodules](http://chrisjean.com/2009/04/20/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/).  They would still technically be separate repositories, but can be managed from within the parent repository.